# Why is my cat following and keeping an eye on my other cat?

Tags: cats, behavior, aggression, multi-pet-families, vocalizations

Some context: I have two cats, one male (Gatão, 3-5 years old) and one female (Pitica, 1-2 years old). Pitica has been spayed before I took her in, Gatão has been spayed since last week. They came from the same house, so even though they tolerate each other, I wouldn't say they are friendly to each other either.

The issue I'm having started two days ago. Gatão has been acting weird towards Pitica and meowing a lot. I observed them yesterday and today and I came to the conclusion that he is "keeping an eye" on her. For example, he is always following her around. When she sits or lies down, he also sits or lies down in a position from which he can see her, and he watches her from there. When she is sleeping inside the house, he sleeps too, but when he hears her go out, he wakes up and follows her. When she leaves his field of view, he looks for her desperately and meows continuously while doing so; when he finds her, he stops meowing, sits and watches her.

He does this all day long and she seems extremely stressed by it. She hisses at him and runs away from him, but he never stops following her around.

What could be happening? Should I be concerned? Will this behaviour fade away or should I do something to help them?

Answer (score 1):

Gatão is being friendly. When cats are friends, they will "hang out" by simply staying near each other. If one cat moves, the other is likely to follow. Only the most affectionate cats will actually cuddle with each other and groom each other as a sign of friendship.  Otherwise, you can tell your cats are friends if you usually see them peacefully in the same room together.

However, I think there is a chance that Gatão is actually getting anxious when Pitica leaves him, which could be the reason why he so desperately meows when she is not there.  Furthermore, it seems pretty clear that Pitica does not want to be as close as Gatão wants, since she is hissing at him.

It might help to try to keep Gatão more entertained throughout the day, so that he is not so dependent on Pitica. I would try to give them regular play sessions every day, and to make sure they have things to do while you aren't there. For instance, make sure your windows are easily accessible to them, so they can comfortably look out. If you can, set up a bid feeder outside your window, so they have lots of birds to look at. Food puzzle toys are also good for keeping them distracted.

If nothing you do seems to calm Gatão, then you might also consult your vet about it.

Answer (score -1):

Your cat could be protecting your other cat. He could be keeping an eye on her due to previous experiences or an attack. Either that or he just wants to keep an eye on her for the heck of it. I would say see if it gets worse, then take them both to the vet.